# How to export variable (s3 bucket name) from bash (YAML) to python file

Tags: python, bash, yaml, terraform

I have terraform-intgr.yml file which performs terraform init, plan, apply task. Also, I have s3 bucket name in output.tf.
terraform steps completed successfully and I can exported s3 bucket name in .yml file. But, I can't access variable 'S3_BUCKET_NAME' from python file. Getting None(no value) for this value in python code.

Can you please assist in how to access s3 bucket name in python code?

output.tf:

```
output "s3_bucket_name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
}
```

terraform-intgr.yml:

```yaml
run:
  path: /bin/bash
  args:
    - -excl
    - | # yaml multiline
      ...
      ...
      export S3_BUCKET_NAME=$(terraform output s3_bucket_name)
```

app.py:

```py
def __init__(self):
        bucket_name = os.environ['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
        print(bucket_name)`
```

Comment: The trouble isn't in python. You have read from the environment correctly. The problem is that whatever is running the terraform from that yaml file is only exporting it to the context of its subshell.

Comment: @theherk Thank you, I think I got your point. Pipeline container environment and python application container environment seems to be different and cannot shared the env variables.